# NullPointerException when calling setText on a TextView outside activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an app using two tabs with different layouts, which means I have three total layouts at the moment:

activity_main,
fragment_receive,
fragment_send

In my onCreate method in my main activity, the following line sets my content view to activity_main. (If anyone could explain why this layout appears to be blank and yet my app still shows both tabs, that would be great.)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Then I use the findViewById method to set a TextView to a view that appears in both fragment_receive.xml and fragment_send.xml.

```
currentExchangeRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exchangeRateView);
```

Then I attempt to use the setText method on this TextView.

```
currentExchangeRate.setText(Double.toString(lastPrice));
```

This line gives me the NullPointerException.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Check which one of `currentExchangeRate ` or `lastPrice` is `null` when you try to set the text. Either has to be if that line gives you the NPE. And then find out why and act accordingly. Adapt and overcome style.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` called from the `Activity`, looks for the id in the hierarchy of views of the `Activity`.

if you want to perform that on the `Fragment` hierarchy, you have to call it from the `Fragment` view, for example `view.findByById()` from the `Fragment` `onCreateView`, after you inflated the layout.

Comment: Alright, so I can now change the TextView only the onCreate method is called for the fragment. How to I access things like EditTexts which are changed after the tab is inflated?

Comment: for correct separation of concerns, your Fragment should be a black box, create a public method in the Fragment such as `setText()` or `getText()` and call it from the activity with `fragment.getText()`, where `fragment` is the Fragment instance (which you get from the `FragmentManager` either by storing it when you create the `Fragment` or by finding the instance)

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
currentExchangeRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exchangeRateView);
```

The compiler finds that the static int ID does exist within your R.id because you declared them in your fragments, and therefore doesn't throw a compiler error. But at runtime, the current view layout (the one you set with setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);) doesn't hold that ID and therefore returns null.

To access your textview that exists within your Fragment from the Controlling Activity, you use the Fragment Manager (add an id property to your fragments in activity xml, or set tags when you declare your Fragments in your code):

```
ReceiveFragment receiveFragment = (ReceiveFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.receive_fragment);
TextView tv = (TextView) receiveFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.exchangeRateView);
tv.setText(Double.toString(lastPrice));
```

Comment: I'm understanding a lot of what you're saying, but I'm stuck on this: `add an id property to your fragments in activity xml` How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` retrieves the view with the requested id **from your activity's layout**

To get your fragment's textview, make the view that your fragments `onCreateView` is returning a static variable and initialize it in the `onCreateView.`

Then you can retrieve the textview like this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) YourFragmentTitle.yourFragmentViewTitle.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```